# Какие типы данных использовать для хранение в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Какие типы данных нужно использовать для хранения в MySQL телефона (79991112233), время в формате timestamp?

Comment: varchar, текстовое поле

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INT` для таймстампа и если для хранения телефона планируете использовать исключительно число тогда `BIGINT`, если же использовать символы `+`, `(`, `)`, то есть телефон в формате строки, тогда VARCHAR

Answer (score 0):

Для телефона чаще всего используют текст (varchar(20)), так как неизвестно в каком формате необходимо будет хранить телефон в будущем. 
При этом необходимо будет на формат телефона наложить ограничения регуляркой на форме ввода телефона (js input mask) и на стороне php в обработке формы. Так будет безопаснее всего и не нужно будет каждый раз преобразовывать при чтении из бд.

Comment: В формате "только цифры", максимальная длина MSISDN установлена в 15 цифр.